# KendoUI Grid inline editor DefaultValue bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, casting, kendo-ui, nullable, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid with ***inline editing*** functionality. Problem is, upon rendering, the grid throws an error while binding a `nullable decimal` datatype in `DefaultValue` property.

I use this code to bind `DefaultValue`.

```
decimal? val = 0M; //nullable decimal 
model.Field(columnSetting.Member, memberType).DefaultValue(val);
```

Here's the error:

> Invalid cast from 'System.Decimal' to
>   'System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

My model has a **`nullable decimal`** datatype in it so the grid should expect the same datatype. But still, it throws this error. Is this a KendoGrid bug? Or am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of KendoUI?

Comment: I'm currently using `KendoUI Q2 2012 SP1 (version 2012.2.913)`

Comment: I would try upgrading to the latest version to see if that resolves it before digging into it too much. I've seen similar issues in some forum posts that were resolved with upgrading. http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new.aspx

Comment: i have read their release notes but I found nothing that seems relevant to my problem. but will try upgrading anyway. thanks!

Comment: Please report back with how it goes...